# KVO-compliant dependent readonly property in category

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-category

I have a class that I need to extend by a (readonly) property exposing a collection. That collection is not backed by an instance variable. Instead it contains a filtered subset of elements of another collection declared on the same class. I need that subset property to be KVO compliant so I can bind to it. I can't manipulate or subclass my particular class to achieve that, so I need to accomplish my goal in a category.

In the case of a non-collection property depending on a non-collection property it would be very simple to make it KVO compliant even in a category. I could just implement

```
+ (NSSet<NSString *> *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForDependentProperty {
  return [NSSet setWithObject:@"originalProperty"];
}
```

However [where Apple suggests that](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html), the documentation also states: "The `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` method does not support key-paths that include a to-many relationship." Indeed it doesn't. And how should it? The KVO framework can't know in which way and when a dependent collection will change when the original collection is altered. For that problem Apple than proposes two solutions:

1. Either registering as observer for the relevant key paths or
2. Registering for notifications of the responsible `NSManagedObjectContext` instance in case of using Core Data.

Since I am using a category both options seem to be inapplicable. Where would I register and (safely) unregister? I can't just start replacing methods of the base class like `- (instancetype)init;` or `dealloc`, and I can't extend them because I'm not in a subclass, so no calls to `super`. What is the best way to achieve this? Method swizzling? Mixing in some dirty lowland C code I haven't heard about yet calling to the Obj-C runtime? Something very obvious I've overlooked? To keep things simple: In my case it would suffice if I can send just `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` messages for my dependent property on *every* change of the original property, no matter the kind of change.

`FinalClass.h`:

```
@interface FinalClass : ...

@property NSSet *someCollection;
...

@end
```

`FinalClass+Category.h`

```
@interface FinalClass (Category)

@property (readonly) NSSet *someCollectionSubset;

@end
```

`FinalClass+Category.m`

```
@implementation FinalClass (Category)

+ (NSSet<NSString *> *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForSomeCollectionSubset {
  // Not working here because the key path contains a to-many relationship
  return [NSSet setWithObject:@"someCollection"];
}

- (NSSet *)someCollectionSubset {
  // Change notifications for that subset needed
  // No mutations needed, primitive change notifications would do
  return [self.someCollection filteredSetUsingPredicate:...];
}

@end
```

Comment: At least `some` must start with capital `S` in `keyPathsForValues….`

Comment: Ah, I get it, thanks. I've edited my post now and corrected the capitalization of the Some in the second part of the sample code for clarity. However that unfortunately doesn't solve the problem and that mistake isn't present in my actual code.

Comment: Implement the property somewhere else, where you can register observers. Or do the filtering somewhere else. Is this question about Core Data and `NSArrayController`?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what kind of changes the subset should support? To-many relationship actually implies tracking changes in elements of the collection, not the collection itself. `NSet` is not even mutable, so `keyPathsForValuesAffecting<Key>` should work as expected if you change the set as a whole. 

P.S. Also the method should be `keyPathsForValuesAffectingSomeCollectionSubset` not `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForSomeCollectionSubset`

Comment: Thanks @TheDreamsWind, that simple mistake did kill it for me and now everything works as expected. I just needed change messages for the set as a whole. I also found another method with swizzling methods, but I think I'll got into details tomorrow. It's gotten late here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @TheDreamsWind, I've found a very simple answer:

**Simple solution**

Even though the signature of the general method for automatic KVO updates for dependent keys is `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`, the key-specific signature the KVO framework is looking for is `keyPathsForValuesAffecting<Key>` and not `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueFor<Key>`. After I changed my method name accordingly, automatic KVO updates started to work with me.

However that is supposed to work only when the dependency as a whole changes. In my case it also creates simple change messages without set mutations when members of the original collection changes, even though it's not supposed to do so as I understand the documentation.

**Complex solution**

Another solution I found is swizzling the four change message methods `willChangeValueForKey:`, `didChangeValueForKey:`, `willChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:` and `didChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:` with new implementations,  that call the original implementation, as well as generate an additional change message for the dependent key if needed:

```
- (void)willChangeValueForKeySwizzled:(NSString *)key {
    // Call the original implementation
    [self willChangeValueForKeySwizzled:key];
    
    // Send additional change messages if applicable and needed
    if ([FinalClass.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForDependentProperty containsObject:key]) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(dependentProperty))];
    }
}

...
```

That approach could be used to generate also set mutation change messages for better efficiency. In my case, that efficiency gain would mean premature (over)optimizing, so I stick with the simple solution proposed.

Comment: The point here is that `+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key` signature is pre-defined and cannot be changed. All classes derived from `NSObject` [inherit this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1414299-keypathsforvaluesaffectingvaluef), and handle in hierarchical manner. KVO either check this exact method (where the key is the argument) OR a method which follows `keyPathsForValuesAffecting<Key>` convention (and there is no such convention as `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueFor<Key>`)